# How to copy a file from a USB drive to C drive in Windows 10 using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy-paste, usb-drive

I have some files in a USB drive which need to be copied to multiple computers. These files contain an executable which will use the other config files. 
My issue is, for Windows 10 PCs, while the temp_folder gets created, none of the files get copied.

For windows 7 I was able to create a batch file which copied the files to the local drive and ran the executable using the config files.

The batch file contents were as below :

```
mkdir C:\temp_installer
copy ".\file_name" "C:\temp_installer"
<rest of the code>
```

I have tried using xcopy and robocopy, but still see the batch file run and just stop at creating the folder. The same issue isn't observed in Windows 7.

Has someone tried this or can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you running the script? ".\file_name" is a relative path. You create "temp_installer" in the same directory you are copying from, and presumably your file is copied to a file (not directory) named "C:\temp_installer"

Comment: are you running this script directly from the USB? It seems as if you are running it from the USB itself, if that is the case, it would not have worked on Windows 7 either due to the fact that you `mkdir` on the actual USB. Will post a solution as answer anyway.

Comment: Using either one of `XCopy` or its successor, `RoboCopy`, you can both copy and create the directory in one command. _It is of course advisable that you try do do so to a location where you have sufficient privileges, Windows provides, both system and user temp directories, for exactly this purpose._

Comment: Sorry, I need to correct the code in my question. the mkdir command is run to create a C drive directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a better option, we do not need to be concerened about permission issues on the root of `C:`

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
set "inst_dir=%temp%\temp_installer"
mkdir "%inst_dir%">nul 2>&1
for %%i in (*) do if not "%%i"=="%~nx0" copy /Y "%%i "%inst_dir%"
:# When completed, we can call execute the files from "%inst_dir%"
```

The `for` loop is not needed to be honest, I am only doing it to **not** copy the `.bat`/`.cmd` file itself to the folder as there would be no need for it there.

Or even simpler, without having to do all the above, you could just use `robocopy`

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
robocopy /MIR .\ "%temp%\temp_installer"
```

Comment: Thank you, while this works, I now have a weird issue. When I double click the batch file everything is copied as expected. However, when I run as an administrator robocopy starts copying my entire windows directory to the newly created folder. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: Your working directory changes when running as admin.

Comment: cool, if you want to see why create a new batch and add `echo %cd%` then next line `echo %~dp0` and last line `pause`. then run it as admin to see the results and why we do `cd /d %~dp0`. You can then open `cmd.exe` and run `call /?` to learn all you need about substitution of batch parameters. `:)` good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is your friend here, try this:

```
Copy-Item E:\Document\ C:\Temp\Document\ -R
```

Works great for me and it even creates destination directory, also `Copy-Item` has `alias` `cp` and `copy`.

If you running some sort of script, you might have issues with `Execution-Policy`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6